# custom routing in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

Is it possible to route the url to a custom action like this ..

```
Router::connect('/data/:controller/{$action}/:id', array('action'=>$action+"_save", '[method]' => 'POST', 'data' => true), array('id' => '[0-9]+', 'pass' => array('id')));
```

I tried the above line but it says undefined variable $action. But in example i saw that this is possible for prefix

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can route the url to a custom valid action whatever you want:

```
Router::connect('/data/:controller/{$action}/:id', array('action'=>$action."_save",     '[method]' => 'POST', 'data' => true), array('id' => '[0-9]+', 'pass' => array('id')));
```

Use '.' instead of '+' in 'action' parameter.

Comment: That was one gotcha .. but it still complains about undefined variable action. Are you using this form in your current project ? can you show   some other example ?